# PHP Loop While Else

Tags: mysql, if-statement, while-loop

The below code creates a list of geographical regions and a sublist of specialists working in said region e.g.

- Region 1
- Region 2

  - Mr A Nother
- Region 3

  - Mr A Nother
- Region 4

If a region does not have any specialists (in the above example regions 1 and 4), then I'd like it to say something along the lines of "no specialists working in this region".   I think my query may be preventing this from working, but I'd be grateful for any solutions and comments on whether this is the best approach (I don't know much about PHP coding).

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `local_authority` ORDER BY `name` ASC";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$query) { error(mysql_error()); }

        while($authority = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {


        $asql = "SELECT * FROM `specialists` as s, `users` as u WHERE s.authority_id = '". $authority['authority_id'] ."' AND s.user_id = u.user_id";

        $aquery = mysql_query($asql);

        if(!$aquery) { error(mysql_error()); }

echo("$authority[name]<br>");

            while($specialist = mysql_fetch_array($aquery)) {

                echo("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $specialist[forename] $specialist[surname] <br>");


         }

    }
```

Comment: Mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should look into mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't made a website in a while and found out about the depreciation today.  I need to read up on mysqli!

Comment: *...whether this is the best approach...* Hitting the database multiple time is a **bad approach**. You can get all the data you need in one go using an outer join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!$aquery) { error(mysql_error()); }

if(mysql_num_rows($aquery) == 0){
  echo "There are no specialists in this area.";
}else{

  echo("$authority[name]<br>");

  while($specialist = mysql_fetch_array($aquery)) {

    echo("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $specialist[forename] $specialist[surname] <br>");

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I was just about to upload this as a solution, I found it 15 mins after posting!

Comment: Np :). Good luck with your site :D.